# How to extract and parse an attribute from an element in an XML File in Powershell

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I have a powershell script reading an xml file. I need to extract the Name attribute from the following Application element in that xml file and then parse out the value so the end result looks like this "abcApplication"

```xml
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/abcApplication" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
```

What's the best/easiest way of doing that in Powershell? The end result is going into a JSON file.

This is what I have so far:

```ps1
$appParametersFileName = "$appParameterFilePath\$appParameterFile"
        
$appParametersXml = [Xml] (Get-Content "$appParametersFileName") 
$parameterJsonFile = "$appParameterFilePath\$applicationFolderName"+ "." + $jsonFileName
# Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
# Convert any values that can be interpreted as [int] to [int] and strip out any comments in the xml file.
$hash = [ordered] @{}
$appParametersXml.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -ne 'Comment'} | % {
$hash[$_.Name] = @{ value = if ($num = $_.Value -as [int]) { $num } else { $_.Value }
   }
}
$hash["clusterName"]=@{ value=$clusterName}
$hash["applicationName"]=@{ value=$applicationInstanceName}
$hash["applicationTypeName"]=@{ value=$applicationTypeName}
$hash["applicationTypeVersion"]=@{ value=$applicationVersion}
$hash["appPackageURL"]=@{ value=$appPackageURL}

# Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
[ordered] @{
'$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
 contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
 parameters = $hash
 } | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File $parameterJsonFile
 Write-Host "The JSON File is: " $parameterJsonFile
```

Comment: ```$appParameters.Application.Name.Split(“:/“)[1]``` should give you the result, but that’s making some assumptions about the format of the value based purely on a sample size of one. You might need to tweak it if my assumptions aren’t correct...

Comment: Thank you! That worked by changing [1] to [2]!